# Adding # in python password string

Tags: python, string, string-literals

how to add # in python password of string type. Below is the code and it is commenting everything after `#`.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="abc.dhgh.com",user="XXXXXX",passwd="XXXXXXXXXXXX#",db="XXXXXXXXX")
```

but when i am running with the below code (storing password in a variable and sending)

```
pwd="XXXXXXXXXXXX#"
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="abc.dhgh.com",user="XXXXXX",passwd=pwd,db="XXXXXXXXX")
```

it is working fine . Why the first code doesnot work and why the second code does work? can you please explain this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't get your question. This code doesn't contain comments. By any chance you missed `"` after the # sign?

Comment: @chen-a Is this possible, that he's asking about escaping ?...  Looks like an unsalvageable question...

Comment: If your syntax highlighter shows everything after # as a comment - get a better one, # here is a part of a string.

Comment: db = MySQLdb.connect(host="abc.dhgh.com",user="XXXXXX",passwd="XXXXXXXXXXXX#",db="XXXXXXXXX")

Comment: @sr9yar sorry.My question was not clear.I guess that's why you misunderstood me.I solved the the code problem .But I am little curious about the behaviour.I edited my question.Please have a look at it